# How to filter array with filter settings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I'm stuck with Array, objects and filters. I have the following code and I want to filter the (array)list with my filter settings. and then do something with it. I am using React as frame work. But i think this is pure Javascript.

Am I in the right direction?

```
filterSettings = { flagA: false, flagB: true, FlagC: true};
        list = [
            {flag: a, txt: 'some text1'},
            {flag: a, txt: 'some text2'},
            {flag: b, txt: 'some text3'},
            {flag: b, txt: 'some text4'},
            {flag: c, txt: 'some text5'},
            {flag: c, txt: 'some text6'},
        ] 

        list.filter(
            // if(filtersettings.a === true) show flags with a 
            //else{hide flags with a}
            // if(filtersettings.b === true) show flags with b 
            //else{hide flags with b}
            ///...ect
        ).map((item)=>{
            console.log(item);
        });
```

Comment: Did you try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2722213/6761781) on another SO post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the `filterSettings` keys correspond with the flag values you can just use the `filterSettings` value (which is a boolean value) as a test for the filter:

```js
let filterSettings = { a: false, b: true, c: true};
let list = [
    {flag: 'a', txt: 'some text1'},
    {flag: 'a', txt: 'some text2'},
    {flag: 'b', txt: 'some text3'},
    {flag: 'b', txt: 'some text4'},
    {flag: 'c', txt: 'some text5'},
    {flag: 'c', txt: 'some text6'},
] 

let filtered = list.filter( item => filterSettings[item.flag]) // filterSettings[item.flag] will be a boolean
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 variables a,b,c to handle the three cases then use filter()

```
var a,b,c;
var new_list = list.filter((item)=>{
    if(filterSettings.flagA==true && item.flag=="a")
    {
         return a.push(item);
    }
    else if(filterSettings.flagB==true && item.flag="b")
    {
         return b.push(item);
    }
   else(filterSettings.flagC==true && item.flag=="c")
   {
         return c.push(item);
   }
}
```

To get the final result use .length property to check which one is more than 0

```
if (a.length>0){
    console.log(a)
}
else if (b.length>0){
    console.log(a)
}
else(c.length>0){
    console.log(a)
}
```

Comment: a,b,c are three array that hold each cases

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the specific objects and the function [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for looping the filtered array.

*I'm assuming you don't know the function [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and its purpose because the way you're using will return an array with undefined values*

```js
const filterSettings = { a: false, b: true, c: true},
      list = [    {flag: 'a', txt: 'some text1'},    {flag: 'a', txt: 'some text2'},    {flag: 'b', txt: 'some text3'},    {flag: 'b', txt: 'some text4'},    {flag: 'c', txt: 'some text5'},    {flag: 'c', txt: 'some text6'}],
      handler = ({flag}) => filterSettings[flag];

list.filter(handler).forEach(item=> console.log(item))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```